# Why isn't Express a middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

This might be an obvious question, but I am new to node.js.

Express seems to alias Connect (`express()` instead of `connect()`, etc). Given that Connect is already a middleware framework, what does Express provide that couldn't be a simple Connect middleware and required this wrapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express did originate from connect. For a long time it has used most of connect's middlewares. Originally express was described as Sinatra like framework. Sinatra(in ruby) introduced domains and routing over the http server e.g. thin. Express's router is heavily influenced by Sinatra. Some time earlier Connect dropped support for routing. Its developers aimed for it to become a middleware ecosystem over http, so that many frameworks can be built upon it. After that they went separate ways.

Express is more full-featured and flexible http server. Connect is supposedly a low-level framework (you will have to do some scaffolding yourself). Express has evolved from a connect wrapper although it looks very similar.

Now Koa is inspired from express/connect's middleware architecture. It uses new Ecmascript-6 features for its middleware chain.

Comment: But if Connect is low-level framework, why Express does not extend it instead of wrapping it (and re-inventing it in 4 as specified in other answer)?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin Partly due to differences between the communities. If Senchalabs decides to brings some changes to Connect it will directly affect Express. When router was removed, it was one of the most used features of connect. The express developers saw this as a bad sign. Since Sinatra like routing was the very essence of Express its survival was in the question. I don't think it was decision by choice. To my understanding Connect received lot of support from the community which it did not reciprocate. Connect has a strong foundation thanks to all those contributors.

Answer (score 2):

As of Express 4, [connect is no longer a dependency](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#overview).

Express adds more functionality just like how Connect adds functionality on top of a plain HTTP server. This includes features like:

- Easier, more flexible routing
- Support for views
- Support for reverse proxies and ETags
- A large number of helper functions on request, response, and application objects
- etc...

Nowadays, Connect is [pretty barebones](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/tree/877e07cfae714f1224584b7d3e44d1d8616e3de4/lib) and mostly just supports the use of middleware -- no other features.

Comment: So it is now an alternative middleware framework? That helps with understanding.

Comment: Yes, it's the same functionality (middleware) plus everything else.